# Google Data Studio report not refreshing from MySql

Tags: looker-studio

I have experimented with connecting Google Data Studio to one of our Mysql servers (Amazon RDS) and created a couple of reports. Everything is working great except that the reports are not refreshing automatically. I have to do it manually by pressing the "refresh data" button on the report.

Have anyone else experienced similar issues?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

Luckely, I've found the workaround solution:

1. Install a plugin [Data Studio Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-studio-auto-refresh/inkgahcdacjcejipadnndepfllmbgoag)
2. Configure plugin on regular update (e.g. each 5 min)
3. Open Datastudio report in the background
4. After each 5 min - connections will be automatically refreshed.
5. Hooray! Use up-to-date reports.

**P.S.** IN GDS tracker - [opened bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62531710) to resolve autoupdate issue without any timelines :(